# How do we use the words "other", "another" and "the other"?

Tags: word-meaning

Could explain the difference between these words below?

> **other**
>
> **another**

and

> **the** other

Comment: There's nothing special about *other*, here. The entire difference is due to the article used: zero, indefinite, or definite. So you should look into how articles are used in English to understand how they're being applied to *other* and what the consequent differences in meaning are.

Comment: Can you give us some context and tell us about your prior research. E.g. [other](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/other?s=t), [another](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/another?s=t)

Comment: There's also the possibility of *a [whole] **nother** [ball game]*.

Comment: other= there is no specific other, the other= there is some specific other, another = one other thing. That's my take.

Comment: @Cardinal: But if *another = one other thing*, how come we're always talking about [*one thing **and** another?*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22one+thing+and+another%22)

Comment: @FumbleFingers How does *one thing and one other thing* not make sense?

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey: What with one thing and another, I never really got around to figuring out why we don't just say *What with **two** things* (or should that be *What with two **other** things?*). Actually, that particular usage doesn't make an awful lot of sense, since it literally refers to just ***two*** things, but in practice we always use it to mean some unspecified number much larger than two.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Let's consider this scenario: You are describing something, for example a person. You may say. He is very humble and amiable. Another aspect of his character is that he is very diligent employee. I meant that I usually see "another" in texts when the author's intention is to imply "**an** other thing". BTW, I eager to learn more.

Comment: @Cardinal: Okay, here's another little snippet for you! The (primarily, *Northern UK*) dialectal contraction of **the** to **'t** is fast dying out. *Except* in the context of **t'other**, which is not uncommon among speakers who don't even speak one of the regional accents where it is / was "natural". I don't know if that's related to **'nother** as per my first comment (though I've always assumed that one's more a US thing).

Answer (score 1):

Another – is used with singular nonspecific countable nouns; a/an are not need

```
I do not like that book. Do you have another book?
I do not want to look for another problem. I have enough problems.
I do not like my car. I want to buy another car.
```

Other – is used with plural or uncountable nonspecific nouns

```
I do not like those books. Do you have other books?
Do you have other kinds of cakes? I do not like yellow cake.
I do not want to look for any other problems. I have enough problems.
```

The Other – is used with specific singular, plural countable and uncountable nouns

```
I do not like these books. I want the other book that is in your room.
I do not like that yellow cake. Can I have the other cake on the shelf.
We want to go to the other food store, that is up the street.
```

Answer (score 1):

These are the three possible article forms of the adjective "other":

1. Indefinite (another)
2. Definite (the other)
3. No article (other).

This is like any other adjective, except that "another" is a contraction of "an other".

Consider a comparison with the adjective *old*:

- **I saw an old house** vs. **I saw another house** *(an unspecified, single house)*
- **I saw the old house** vs. **I saw the other house** *(a specific house; single one)*.
- **I saw old houses / the old houses** vs. **I saw other houses / the other houses** *(Unspecified or specific both take no article if there are more than one).*